# Web forms: body onload event can't find a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, dom-events

I come from MVC background and I have little experience with web forms.

I have established where the problem is, but so far I have been unable to fix this.

I have a form which is meant to execute Javascript function when body of the form loads. Please notice that head tag has a run at server attribute as it needs to use `Request.QueryString`.

The code is below:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    
<script type="text/javascript">

    function doSomething()
    {
        // Use web forms to do something
        var foo = <%= Request.QueryString["input"] %>;
    }
    
</script>
<title>Foo</title>
</head>
<body onload="doSomething()">
    <form id="MainForm" runat="server">
    <table width="272px" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td class="body">
                ...
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I get the following error:

SCRIPT5007: The value of the property `doSomething` is null or undefined, not a Function object.

My guess is that something executes on a server or other way round. This has worked previously (over a year ago), so potentially something in a web config was overwritten. I have spent the most of day on this and had no luck so far.

Edit: Generated output is below

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    
<script type="text/javascript">

    function doSomething()
    {
        debugger;                 
        var o = crmForm.queryString;    
    }
    
</script>


    <title></title>
</head>
<body onload="doSomething()">
    <form name="MainForm" method="post" action="fooPage.aspx?input=queryString" id="MainForm">
<div>
// hidden fields
    <table width="272px" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td class="body">
                // inputs
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could try removing the `runat="server"` from the head tag.

Comment: Could you post how your final markup looks like? Also you do not need to use `runat="server"` in order to execute server side expressions. This being said the server side expression doesn't seem to be wrapped in quotes. Are you sere that `input` is an integer. Because if it isn't, the `foo` variable will be undefined.

Comment: @CodeRush, in the generated HTML you seem to be using some `crmForm.queryString` variable which I can't see being defined anywhere. If you replace the code in the `doSomething` with an alert, put this in an HTML page and run in a browser it works perfectly fine. So there must something else in your HTML that you haven't shown.

Comment: Hi, Generated HTML lays within IFrame. QueryString is a variable within a parent document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the `onload` attribute of the `body` tag, you can also add the following code within the `<script>` tags:

```
if(window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener("load", doSomething, true);
else window.onload = doSomething;
```